# Retrieving comments from "Facebook Comments" social plugin

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-rest-api, facebook-social-plugins

Assume I have a website with Facebook comments (social plugin) [like this](http://www.ct24.cz/media/98075-ct24-nabizi-zive-vysilani-pro-iphone/).

Is it possible to get the comments from this site using the FQL or "[comments.get](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/comments.get/)" method of the REST API (note the responsible FB app is not mine)? It might be possible somehow, since the comments are displayed on the web arbitrarily...

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the comments with the `comments.get` method. You'll need to use the Unique ID every of your Comments-Widgets has as the first parameter (`xid`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Andre, however, it doesn't work for me, the FB app that manages that social plugin is not mine (I edited the question to mention this). https://api.facebook.com/method/comments.get?xid=98075 is not enough...

Comment: Yep, but I don't know any other way to obtain it than to send the user to the auth - which is not what happens on the web, the comments are just there... :( Possibly this is the REST API thing...

Answer (score 0):

There is Graph API call for that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://your.domain/your_url.html
```